# Freeing DOM element memory / resources created by ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have created a web page that displays data retrieved from a database via a `jQuery` `$.ajax` call. The web page is part of a digital signage system that will be displayed continuously.

The `$.ajax` response is formatted HTML generated server side. This HTML is then inserted into a `div` element after removing any existing HTML from the `div`.

I then attach a `jQuery` marquee plugin (http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin) to some of the newly created `div` elements with the `.marquee` class.

```
var marqueeCounter = 0;
var appBusy = false;

function update() {
    if (appBusy == false) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/get/html/from/server',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#div-container').empty();
                $('#div-container').html('');
                $('#div-container').html(response);

                $('.marquee').each(function () {
                    $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
                });

                $('.marquee').bind('beforeStarting',function () {
                    appBusy = true;
                    marqueeCounter++;
                }).bind('finished', function () {
                    $(this).marquee('pause');
                    marqueeCounter--;
                    if (marqueeCounter < 1) {
                        appBusy = false;
                    }
                }).marquee({
                    duration: 3500,
                    allowCss3Support: true,
                    duplicated: false
                });
            }
        });
    }

    setTimeout(update, 5000);
}
```

The problem I am facing is that after hours of running this app, the marquees gradually slow down and eventually the browser (firefox) crashes.

Looking at the memory usage in firefox and chrome, the elements that are replaced with each `$.ajax` call don't seem to be freed from memory and the eventually choke the browser.

The DOM element count goes up and up as does memory usage.

I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong here but cannot figure out how to free these resources up.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
I have tried using the plugins destroy method as per the example on the developers page but it didn't help.

I have removed references to the plugin which results in the following code:

```
function update() {
    if (appBusy == false) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/get/html/from/server',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#div-container').empty();
                $('#div-container').html(response);
                }
        });
    }

    setTimeout(update, 5000);
}
```

The number of nodes continues to grow and never decreases.

**EDIT 2:**
I have re-written this function in native javascript and the problem seems to have gone away.

```
function update()
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else    {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
                }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                                    {
                                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                                        {
                                        document.getElementById("div-container").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                        }
                                    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/get/html/from/server", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    setTimeout(update, 5000);
    }
```

Why would `jQuery` be returning different results?

Comment: Your code looks fine (other than you can get rid of `$('#div-container').html('');`). I would check to see what elements that the marquee plugin is creating, and if they are all being removed at the appropriate times. Also check if it has a `destroy` method you can call before updating the content within the AJAX success handler.

Comment: `$('#div-container').empty();` i think you can use this line before ajax call. so it would clear the div before filling with other.

Comment: The marquee plugin appears to have a [`destroy` method](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee#methods) - I would suggest putting that in your code also before emptying out the container (only if it's been initialised), then retesting.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have tried your suggestions but to no avail. Having `.empty()` outside of the `ajax` call didn't help but also caused an obvious visual refreshing of data. I also tried the `destroy` method but that also didn't make any difference. I have edited my question above.

Comment: I have rewritten the function in plain old javascript and the problem seems to have gone. Is there something I need to do differently in jQuery?